# GE Digital Energy UPS Monitor for Windows

Tags: ups

I have a few GE Digital Energy Match Series UPS that beeps and shutdown seconds after startup and before output power is supplied. The batteries are at full capacity. So I searched a number of sites for configuration software in order to determine the settings. UPS Monitoring for Linux seems like a viable option. However, PC runs on Windows Vista. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Software including a compatibility list can be found in a [GE publication library](http://www.geindustrial.com/publibrary/family/uninterruptible-power-supplies-ups-single-phase/software).  For anything more specific, probably contact the vendor.

That Vista machine is an end of life security risk that needs to be addressed. Preferably by replacing it with newer software.